# How can I access data that's stored in my App Delegate from my various view controllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ipad

This question is similar to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662582/sharing-data-between-views-through-app-delegate), but I'm new to iPhone development and I'm getting used to the good practices for organizing my data throughout my app.  I understand the ApplicationDelegate object to be the best place to manage data that is global to my app, correct?  If so, how can I access data that's stored in my App Delegate from various view controllers?  For example, my array is created in the app delegate as such...

**appdelegate.m**

```
sectionTitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Title1", @"Title2", @"Title3", nil];
rootViewController.appDelegate = self;
```

and I need to access it throughout the different views of my app, like my root table view controller...

**rootviewcontroller.m**

```
NSUInteger numTableSections = [self.appDelegate.sectionTitles count];
```

Is this the best way to do it or are there any reasons I should organize my data a better way?  I ask because I can never really get too comfortable with using global variables (I blame my college professors), though I'm not sure if this can be considered a global variable.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand the ApplicationDelegate
>   object to be the best place to manage
>   data that is global to my app,
>   correct?

Not really (your college professors had a point). It's tempting to start putting a lot of stuff into the app delegate, but it's not a very sustainable practice. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637739/main-point-of-application-delegate-class/2637914#2637914).

And read [this good post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) by Matt Gallagher for more depth.

That said, I often put something like this in my app delegate header:

```
#define APP_DELEGATE (MyAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

so I can easily do things like:

```
int n = [[APP_DELEGATE sectionTitles]count];
```

Comment: I logged in specifically so I could up vote this. I really think the app delegate is a bad place for global dats. I tend to use singletons for things like that.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
self.appDelegate = ( YourApplicationDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: thanks, that'll free me from keeping track of references to my app delegate in each view.  good tip!